# How use font color in phpexcel module in drupal

Tags: php, drupal-6, phpexcel

I am usign phpexcel module to export excel. I have an array looks following:

```
temp=array(25,26,done|fail);
```

Here "done" should be green color and "fail" should be red color, and `(done|fail)` both come in same cell. What should I do for this?

Alternatively I can move them into seperate cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If done|fail are both displayed in the same cell, then you should look at using a rich text run for that content. There's examples of this in /Tests/05featuredemo.inc.php (e.g. cell A18) and the developer documentation section 4.6.37

Comment: Hi Baker, thanks But this is not working. I am using linux and open excel sheet in open office and save as xls format.

Comment: Work Item #8916 - http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/workitem/8916 - on the PHPExcel issues list, Rich Text for BIFF files.... This issue was resolved in SVN in February, and included in the 1.7.7 production release